# How to test Json data by postman?

Tags: json, json.net, postman

How to send JSON data by the postman.

```
https://192.1xx.xx.xxx:443/api/v1/doors/101?timeout=30
Date: Wed, 28 Nov 2018 05:30:00 -0000
Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8
Authorization: AWS 4c5f0a7ac5f3473692ee8816f03b9081:F9CGxCo6GUMK5jcPFsLfrb8UhXE=
Content-MD5: MPjc6P6oi5KckbiQ97fZVg==

{
    "open": true
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Make a new request under a collection. Put the URI (https://192.1xx.xx.xxx:443/api/v1/doors/101?timeout=30) as endpoint and define the correct request type (one of these: POST/GET/PUT/DELETE etc.). You will see that the `timeout` url parameter is automatically added in the `Params` tab as parameter.

Now click the `Body` tab, select the `raw` radiobutton and select `JSON (application/json)` from the drop down next to it.

Paste the body `{ "open": true }` in the code field under it.

You can add tests to your request with the `Tests` tab and select one or more of the snippets on the right. The `Status code: Code is 200` snippet is always a good on the have.

Press the `Send` button to test your request.

**Please note:**
This is you first time on Stack Overflow. As a SO user, we expect you to put more effort in you post: What have you done, why didn't it work.

Also read the documentation of a tool before you start using it. You are using specialised tooling, expect a learning curve. You can find the documentation here:
https://learning.getpostman.com/
and a nice introduction video here:
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t5n07Ybz7yI